# How to get desktop logon to work on Raspbian Jessie Lite (lightdm fail)?

Tags: raspi-config, desktop, lightdm

Steps to reproduce:

1. copy latest Raspbian Jessie Lite image to sdcard
2. install updates, reboot
3. run raspi-config, choose "boot into Desktop" from boot menu
4. install lightdm package as suggested by raspi-config
5. reboot

After these steps cli is only loaded and lightdm service shows only this:

```
sudo systemctl status lightdm
 lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2017-03-30 11:05:44 UTC; 39s ago
     Docs: man:lightdm(1)
  Process: 854 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lightdm (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 849 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/sbin/lightdm" ] (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 854 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 30 11:05:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
Mar 30 11:05:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit lightdm.service entered failed state.
Mar 30 11:05:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lightdm.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 30 11:05:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Light Display Manager...
Mar 30 11:05:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Mar 30 11:05:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lightdm.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Mar 30 11:05:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
Mar 30 11:05:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit lightdm.service entered failed state.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUI in Linux is modular and client-server. A display manager (as its name suggests) manages your displays, and nothing more. You will need an X server (which doesn't have to be running on the same computer BTW) to have any displays in the first place, and a desktop environment if you want to have something on your display besides a mouse pointer.

The relevant packages to install are `xserver-xorg` and `lxde`, but there's a high chance that I have missed something, so if your goal is to *use* the GUI, just install Raspbian with GUI included.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. raspi-config only suggest to install lightdm package, I thought that raspi-config tool is smart enough to give good suggestion, but it could be that you are right and something is still missing. Maybe this is a bug in dependencies for lightdm package.

Comment: @valentt It's not a bug, this is by design. You can configure `lightdm` to use the X server installed on your PC if you want, meaning you don't have to install it on the RPi. You may also want to run without a desktop environment (think web kiosks). This is why those are not dependencies of `lightdm`

Comment: @Dmitri you were right, after installing xorg and lxde packages now Raspbian boots into gui desktop. I know that Linux is modular, but I would still argue that this is a bug in raspi-config.  When I open raspi-config two options in boot menu are "cli" or "desktop" (no mention of "no X server kiosk mode" or "modular dekstop" that uses remote X server. There is plain vanilla "desktop" option and after it is chosen only suggestion, which I argue is wrong (ie a logical bug), is that it suggest installing lightdm package and nothing else.

Comment: @valentt Sure, I was arguing that `lightdm` should not have `xserver-xorg` as a dependency. I'm not familiar enough with `raspi-config`, but yeah, it would be nice if it did such checks for you when you select "Boot to desktop".

Comment: I've just tried this and just `apt-get install xerver-xorg lxde` (including the recommonded packages) is all you need to add to a fresh install of Raspbian 8 to get an LXDE (not PIXEL) desktop. This does, however, increase disk space usage from about 900 MB to 2.3 GB (1.9 GB after `apt-get clean`), and includes some moderately large things you may not use, such as `firefox-esr` (80 MB) and `gnome-user-guide` (40 MB). Note too that the `apt-get install` can take quite a long time on an SD card—much longer than a fresh install of the full non-light version.

Answer (score 1):

I probably didn't do all this correctly, but maybe this will help someone.

After spending much time trying to get OpenCV working, I found ready to use Image based on Lite. But still in the very Noob stage, decided to get a GUI installed and found this/ 
[GUIDE] [Raspbian Lite with RPD/LXDE/XFCE/MATE/i3/Openbox/X11 GUI][1](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=133691)
Then I installed synaptic and loaded up what I needed without any of the troubles I was having with the OpenCV installation attempts.

Should anyone be interested in the Image: 
[Ready-to-use Image: Raspbian Stretch + ROS + OpenCV](https://medium.com/@rosbots/ready-to-use-image-raspbian-stretch-ros-opencv-324d6f8dcd96)