# B+ start-up memory problem

Tags: boot-issues

I was given a B+ 512Mb bought just before Feb 2015 – perfect timing.
I put togther the kit (which included a snap-together transparent plastic case) & installed the microSD card supplied.  On boot-up I get "Error resizing existing FAT partition. WARNING: you are attempting to use /usr/sbin/parted to operate on (resize) a file system {snip} Warning: File system is reporting the free space as 197868 clusters, not 1097867 clusters."   On close from this I get the NOOBS v1.3.9 screen with a lot of options, none of which may be successfully selected as Disk space is shown as 0MB. The slots in the plastic case are not big enough to attach an SD card and connecting a memory stick via USB port makes no difference.  Any suggestions, please?

Comment: `installed the microSD card supplied` what size is the card (capacity not physical) - you're best option is downloading and writing a new image in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

1.3.9 is a truly ancient version of NOOBS; the latest version is 2.4.0. Don't even try to use such an old version; download the latest one [from the NOOBS download page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) and write that to your card following the instructions given.

Note that if your card is 4 GB or less it's now just a hair too small to install Raspbian PIXEL, the Raspberry Pi version of Debian that includes a full graphical environment. (In that case you should definitely put NOOBS Lite on your card.) However, you'll still be able to install Raspbian Lite (and probably have enough room to [add a basic graphical environment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/64170/65097) if you are careful to do regular `apt-get clean` commands)), and there are also several other interesting operating systems available as well.